# Teradata: What is the purposed of CHECK OPTION when adding a foreign key constraint?

Tags: foreign-keys, constraints, teradata

I can't seem to find a good resource on the internet that explains the `check option` that's used when adding a foreign key constraint.  I've seen it as `with check option` and `with no check option`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addition of `WITH CHECK OPTION` phrase to a `REFERENCES` constraint tells the database to enforce the defined RI constraint at the granularity of a single transaction or request. The system will join the child and parent tables together to see if there is an inconsistency. If an inconsistency is found the entire transaction is rolled back in `TERADATA` session mode or the problem request in `ANSI` mode.

Transversely if you specify `WITH NO CHECK OPTION` the database does not enforce the RI. Thus a record in a child can reference the parent using a value other than NULL when the parent table value does not exist.

RI enforcement is a double edged sword in Teradata and must be evaluated carefully on how you ultimately decide to enforce it. The Teradata Manuals do spell out many of the things that you need to consider to help make your decision. That being said, in the past 15 years that I have been working with Teradata, I have not yet worked on a system where RI was enforced in the data warehouse. *Right, Wrong, or Indifferent.*

Hope this helps.